# How to stub or mock 3rd party library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to stubbing / mocking.

How can I stub methods from an external library so I can only test the methods of my module without actually calling the library?

Also, I'm wondering, is my approach to writing this module the way to go or does it violate some important principle of programming?

```
# file_module.rb
module FileModule
  require 'net/ftp'

  @ftp = nil

  def self.login    
    if !@ftp || @ftp.closed?
      @ftp = Net::FTP.new(Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_server)
      @ftp.login(Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_user, Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_password)
    end
  end

  def self.get_list_of_files_in_directory(directory, type)
    login
    @ftp.chdir("/#{directory}")        
    files = case type
      when "all"            then @ftp.nlst("*")
      when "add"            then @ftp.nlst("*add*")
    end
  end
end

# file_module_spec.rb (RSpec)    
require 'spec_helper'
describe NielsenFileModule do
  describe ".get_list_of_files_in_directory" do
    it "returns correct files for type all" do
      # how to mock Net::FTP or stub all its methods so I simulate the return value of @ftp.nlst("*")?
      NielsenFileModule.get_list_of_files_in_directory("test_folder", "all").count.should eq 6
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to think of this would be to use the principle of [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  You can pass any external dependencies in to the class which you are testing.  In this case the @ftp object.

You're making one error where you're using member variables on an object along with class (or static) methods.

Consider modifying your class to do the following:

```
# file_module.rb
module FileModule
  require 'net/ftp'
  attr_accessor :ftp

  @ftp = Net::FTP.new(Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_server)

  def login    
    if !@ftp || @ftp.closed?
      @ftp.login(Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_user, Rails.configuration.nielsen_ftp_password)
    end
  end

  def get_list_of_files_in_directory(directory, type)
    login
    @ftp.chdir("/#{directory}")        
    files = case type
      when "all"            then @ftp.nlst("*")
      when "add"            then @ftp.nlst("*add*")
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your test, rather than testing class methods on the module, you can test object methods on the module.

```
require 'spec_helper'
class FileClass
  include FileModule
end

let(:dummy) { FileClass.new }
let(:net_ftp) { double(Net::FTP) }
before { dummy.ftp = net_ftp }

describe FileModule do
  describe '.login' do
    context 'when ftp is not closed' do
      before { net_ftp.stub(:closed) { true } }
      it 'should log in' do
        net_ftp.should_receive(:login).once
        dummy.login
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can stub, or set expectations on your net_ftp object like shown above.

Note: There are many ways to do this, but this is a good example that makes a lot of sense.  You're extracting the external service to something that you can double and replace with mocked functionality.

You can also stub out class methods and do some things like:

```
Net::FTP.any_instance.stub
```

when you're more comfortable with what's happening.

Comment: @gmacdokugall's approach is a good one, but there is an insidious problem with the code that could cause frustration: the `@ftp` variable being assigned to on line 6 of `file_module.rb` isn't the same `@ftp` variable that is being referenced in the instance methods.  `self` when `@ftp` is being assigned is the **module**, and `self` in the instance methods is the **instance**, so two different `@ftp` variables are being referenced. One solution would be to have a "getter" instance method for `ftp` that assigns to `@ftp` if it isn't defined already.

Comment: I've always thought dependency injection just for testing is code smell.